# Fetching data using left outer join takes more time

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have one table hostapp_apps and a view host_app_usercount with columns as shown below

```
 hostapp_apps  
======================================================       
 host_app_id || app_type || app_id || platform || user_count

host_app_usercount
======================================================
host_id || TotalUsers
```

Basically I am trying to fetch the app_id, platform, max(usercount), TotalUsers by using the below query

```
 SELECT hostapp_apps.app_type as app_type, host_app_usercount.TotalUsers as Total,
        hostapp_apps.app_id as app_id, MAX(hostapp_apps.user_count) AS sum,
        ROUND((MAX(hostapp_apps.user_count)/(host_app_usercount.TotalUsers) * 100 ),2) AS percentage
FROM pg_datascience.hostapp_apps LEFT OUTER JOIN
     host_app_usercount
     ON (host_app_usercount.host_id=hostapp_apps.host_app_id)
GROUP BY hostapp_apps.app_id, host_app_usercount.TotalUsers
HAVING sum >= 10000
ORDER BY percentage desc
limit 0, 50;
```

But it is taking too long to fetch data. Is there a way to do this without left outer join. Also I tried another way to do this without using join

```
SELECT hostapp_apps.app_type as app_type,
       (select TotalUsers
        from host_app_usercount
        where host_app_usercount.host_id=hostapp_apps.host_app_id
       ) as Total,
       hostapp_apps.app_id as app_id, MAX(hostapp_apps.user_count) AS sum, 
       ROUND((MAX(hostapp_apps.user_count)/(Total) * 100 ),2) AS percentage
 FROM pg_datascience.hostapp_apps
 GROUP BY hostapp_apps.app_id, Total
 HAVING sum >= 10000
 ORDER BY percentage desc
 limit 0, 50;
```

But when I try this I am getting unknown column 'Total' in fields list. Any help is very much appreciated as it is affecting the progress of my task :( Thanks in advance

Comment: Your queries don't really make sense.  Your `GROUP BY` columns and `SELECT` columns are inconsistent.

Comment: Please give an alias to your table for readability.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your first query is not valid.  Your column `app_type` is not an aggregate and is not in the `Group By` clause.  That query is going to give you an error.

Second, it's probably an indexing issue.  You need to look at your indexes and probably create them.  I would create one on each of the following:

> > host_app_usercount.host_id
> >
> > hostapp_apps.host_app_id

That should help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I won't be able to create index in host_app_usercount as it is a View. I have already created index in hostapp_apps table. Is it possible that I can use the second query with some small changes. Thanks again